# Getting an odd Access is Denied error when publishing from VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012 FTP Publish error

Everything works great from VS2010, but from VS2012, using the exact same FTP Publishing config, I get Access is Denied (550) for every file that is being published.

Cant figure it out.. with FTP Publishing, I supply the username/pwd.. and the FTP site...  I have full access, and the process connects fine, but then gives me the error fore each file.  If I set 'remove existing files' it gives me an error of Access is Denied for each file on the server.  so I know it is at least seeing the server (and seeing each file).

THe odd thing is that using that same Username/Pwd and the exact same FTP Publish config with VS2010, it works fine...

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem .... not solved yet , the only solution is to publish the files to your desktop and after upload with one ftp program to your site.... i dont know why FTP on visual studio isnt working yet !